# combine and output tables in loop

Tags: r

I am using a loop to pull in and check stats on a series of files. For each file, I am (1) checking how many observations it has for each state, (2) checking how many ids it has in total and how many unique ids it has; and (3) checking how many ids it has in totals and how many unique ids it has for a specific state.

I am currently just printing out the answers as it runs through the loop, but I want to output it into two tables: the first with the count of observations for each state, and the second with the count of id's and id's for the specific state. This dummy data creates a (very rough) approximation of what I'm doing:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


for(x in 1:100){
  print(x)
  df <- data.frame(
    state =  sample(c(0:72), 1000, replace = TRUE),
    id =  sample(c(100:999), 1000, replace = TRUE)
  )
  
  #table
  print(table(df$state))
  
  #full counts
  print(length(df$id))
  print(length(unique(df$id)))
  
  #specific counts
  print(length(df$id[df$state == 72]))
  print(length(unique(df$id[df$state == 72])))
  
}
```

the output I want in a dataframe / table would basically be:

1: count of each state for x in 1:100; something like this:

```
    x state01 state02 state03
1   1      43     772     455
2   2     509     759     619
3   3     269     930     313
4   4     702     983     120
5   5     455      68     735
6   6     708      12     812
7   7     221     334      25
8   8     746     155     134
9   9     150     831     468
10 10     415     867     261
```

And 2. the count of id's unique id's, and id's and unique id's for a specific state for x in 1:100. Or, something like this:

```
    x   id uid id72 uid72
1   1 1000 395  423   150
2   2 1000 352  541   100
3   3 1000  86  180   32
4   4 1000 202  718   105
5   5 1000 839  135   135
6   6 1000  79  897    30
7   7 1000 437   91    91
8   8 1000 387  287   101
9   9 1000 102  225    85
10 10 1000 310  998   103
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is correct, as 'table 2' doesn't match your example, but would this type of approach solve your problem?

```r
results_table_1 <- list()
results_table_2 <- list()

for(x in 1:100){
  df <- data.frame(
    state = sample(c(0:72), 1000, replace = TRUE),
    id = sample(c(100:999), 1000, replace = TRUE)
  )
  
  result <- as.data.frame(as.integer(table(df$state)))
  colnames(result) <- paste0("state_", x)
  results_table_1[[x]] <- result
  
  results_table_2[[x]] <- data.frame(
    id = length(df$id),
    uid = length(unique(df$id)),
    id72 = length(df$id[df$state == 72]),
    uid72 = length(unique(df$id[df$state == 72]))
  )
}

results_table_1_df <- do.call(cbind, results_table_1)
results_table_2_df <- do.call(rbind, results_table_2)

results_table_1_df
#>    state_1 state_2 state_3 state_4 state_5 state_6 state_7 state_8 state_9
#> 1        9      11      16      17      14      13      24      10      18
#> 2       16      19      14       9      10      21      13       9      12
#> 3       17       9      17      15      12      19      15      15      14
#> 4       13      12      10      19      12      23      13      12      18
#> 5       13      12      18      18      11       7      10      17      12
#> 6       14       7      20       8      14      13      12      10      11
#> 7       11      18      19       7      16      14      14       8       9
#> 8       12      10      12      14       7       8       9      12      22
#> 9       13      16      14      13      20      15      15      18       8
#> 10      12      11      12       7      16      13      14      20      14
#> 11      14      15      15      19      14      12       6      10      23
#> 12      16      18      15      17       9      20      11       9      16
#> 13      15      21      10      11      19      13      18      18      10
#> 14      14      13      14      19      14      17      14      15      14
#> 15      11      19      16      11      12      14      15      16      14
#> 16      11      13      13      10      12      12      10      11      15
#> 17      10      17      15      11      15      12      21      10      12
#> 18      14       9       8      14      14      14      13      12      12
#> 19      13      11      10      18      18      10      14      11      19
#> 20      12      16      16      25      13      14      13      15      23
#> 21      13      17      15       9       9      13      14      14      13
#> 22      10      23      15      13      13      15      12      17      19
#> 23      13      14      15      13      12      10      11      18      19
#> 24      12      18       7      18      16      11       9      15       9
#> 25      23       7      18      14      16      15      15      17      15
#> 26      13      10      13      13      11      10      19      13      11
#> 27      11      11      15      18      20       8      14      17      16
#> 28      13      18      11      14      14      20      19      11       8
#> 29      18      21       9       9      10      11       7      13      12
#> 30      17      13       9       8      13      13      15      13      14
#> 31      20      12      13      16      11      10      17      13      13
#> 32      16      15      15      11      17      14      14      14       9
#> 33       5      14      14      14      13      12       9      17      17
#> 34      11      16      13       8       8      16      11      14      14
#> 35      17      12      18      17      20      29      13       9      14
#> 36      13      17      15      13      15      15      11      11      18
#> 37      14      12      10      16      21      16      14      13      14
#> 38      16      17      13       8       9      10      18      19      18
#> 39      11      12       8       9       3       9      10      16      10
#> 40      11      13      14      16      12      16      16      12      18
#> 41      10      15      15      15      15      12      14      18       9
#> 42      15      16      11      21      11      18      21      11      12
#> 43      15      13      15      10      15      23      11      12      19
#> 44      15      16       9      13      19      15      10      11      17
#> 45      11       7      15      17      11      14      19      20      11
#> 46      11      15      14      10      11      17      15       7      10
#> 47      13       9      10      16      16       9      11      11      11
#> 48      13      14       7      15      12      11      17      11      20
#> 49      19       8      10      10      11      12      14      14      19
#> 50      13      21      11      15      17      14      12      14      13
#> 51      17      12      18      13      15      13      20      18      12
#> 52      14      12      15      14      10      13      11      13       9
#> 53      14      13      13      12      15      20      14      14      13
#> 54      24      19      17      15      14      13      17      16      18
#> 55      18      19      18       8      16       7      14      15      15
#> 56      12      14      17      18      15      14      10      10      12
#> 57      18      11      11      13      12       9      13      13      11
#> 58      14      19      18      14      16       8      12      10      13
#> 59      10      14      18      19      13      13       8      11      20
#> 60      14      12       7      11      14      11       9      12      13
#> 61       8      10      21       6      14      12       7      13      10
#> 62      13      15      16       9      21      11      13      17       9
#> 63      13      23      14      13       9      17      16      14       7
#> 64      13      17      16      17      18      18      13      12      14
#> 65      15      13      13      19       9      15      19      17      11
#> 66      12       6      16      15      17       9       9      17       9
#> 67       9      12      16      10      16      15      11      15      17
#> 68      15       8      16      19      12      17      18      14      10
#> 69      14      11       9       9      13      12      18      15       6
#> 70      12       6      18      14      18      10      13      17      11
#> 71      17      17       8      25      18      16      16      20      17
#> 72      17       6      10      13       8      12      14      13      12
#> 73      15       8      14      13      14      13      19      11      13
...

results_table_2_df
#>       id uid id72 uid72
#> 1   1000 606   15    15
#> 2   1000 600    8     8
#> 3   1000 603   14    14
#> 4   1000 580   13    13
#> 5   1000 611   14    14
#> 6   1000 596   13    13
#> 7   1000 589   19    18
#> 8   1000 614   11    11
#> 9   1000 610   13    13
#> 10  1000 626   18    18
#> 11  1000 586   13    13
#> 12  1000 616   16    16
#> 13  1000 600   17    17
#> 14  1000 612   15    15
#> 15  1000 618   13    13
#> 16  1000 613   12    12
#> 17  1000 608   14    14
#> 18  1000 600   16    16
#> 19  1000 598   11    11
#> 20  1000 613   14    14
#> 21  1000 619   11    11
#> 22  1000 626   12    12
#> 23  1000 598   11    11
#> 24  1000 610   17    17
#> 25  1000 609   12    12
#> 26  1000 600    9     9
#> 27  1000 593   13    13
#> 28  1000 598   16    16
#> 29  1000 612   16    16
#> 30  1000 614   15    14
#> 31  1000 598    9     9
#> 32  1000 587   12    12
#> 33  1000 607   12    12
#> 34  1000 606   15    14
#> 35  1000 602   17    17
#> 36  1000 605   15    15
#> 37  1000 610   14    14
#> 38  1000 596   10    10
#> 39  1000 601   20    19
#> 40  1000 605   21    21
#> 41  1000 603   14    14
#> 42  1000 604   10    10
#> 43  1000 611   12    12
#> 44  1000 608   18    17
#> 45  1000 615   14    14
#> 46  1000 578   17    17
#> 47  1000 608   14    14
#> 48  1000 607   20    20
#> 49  1000 612   14    13
#> 50  1000 593   11    10
#> 51  1000 606   12    12
#> 52  1000 608   21    20
#> 53  1000 595   14    14
#> 54  1000 611   11    11
#> 55  1000 602    8     8
#> 56  1000 611   18    18
#> 57  1000 609   16    16
#> 58  1000 611   17    17
#> 59  1000 598   13    13
#> 60  1000 609   14    14
#> 61  1000 603   12    12
#> 62  1000 584   15    15
#> 63  1000 608   11    11
#> 64  1000 611   19    18
#> 65  1000 604   16    16
#> 66  1000 595   17    17
#> 67  1000 608   18    18
#> 68  1000 607   18    18
#> 69  1000 602   15    15
#> 70  1000 602   10    10
#> 71  1000 611   10    10
#> 72  1000 599   11    11
#> 73  1000 609   20    19
#> 74  1000 605   16    16
#> 75  1000 598   15    15
#> 76  1000 624   11    11
#> 77  1000 588   10    10
#> 78  1000 602   16    16
#> 79  1000 621   15    15
#> 80  1000 587   18    18
#> 81  1000 611    8     8
#> 82  1000 607   12    12
#> 83  1000 614   13    13
#> 84  1000 589   18    18
#> 85  1000 600   21    21
#> 86  1000 611   13    13
#> 87  1000 609   13    13
#> 88  1000 601   13    13
#> 89  1000 599   14    14
#> 90  1000 602   22    22
#> 91  1000 609    8     8
#> 92  1000 594   13    13
#> 93  1000 592   14    14
#> 94  1000 611   12    11
#> 95  1000 594   13    13
#> 96  1000 615   22    22
#> 97  1000 612    7     7
#> 98  1000 608   12    11
#> 99  1000 585   17    17
#> 100 1000 616   10    10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Or using tidyverse functions:

```r
library(tidyverse)

results_table_1 <- list()
results_table_2 <- list()

for(x in 1:100){
  df <- data.frame(
    state = sample(c(0:72), 1000, replace = TRUE),
    id = sample(c(100:999), 1000, replace = TRUE)
  )
  
  results_table_1[[x]] <- df %>%
    mutate(rn = x) %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    summarise(count = n(), rn) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    arrange(state) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = rn,
                names_from = state,
                values_from = count,
                names_prefix = "state_",
                values_fn = unique)
  
  results_table_2[[x]] <- df %>%
    mutate(rn = x,
           id_tmp = id) %>%
    mutate(uid = n_distinct(id_tmp),
           id = length(id)) %>%
    filter(state == 72) %>%
    mutate(id72 = length(id_tmp),
           uid72 = n_distinct(id_tmp)) %>%
    select(-c(state, id_tmp)) %>%
    relocate(rn, .before = id) %>%
    distinct()
}

results_table_1_df <- bind_rows(results_table_1)
results_table_2_df <- bind_rows(results_table_2)

results_table_1_df
#> # A tibble: 100 × 74
#>       rn state_0 state_1 state_2 state_3 state_4 state_5 state_6 state_7 state_8
#>    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#>  1     1      16       9      12      12      16      16      12      14       8
#>  2     2      10      17      18      16      16      11      18      20      17
#>  3     3      10      12       9      11      14      12      10      10      15
#>  4     4      10      12      15      17      12      11      13       5      15
#>  5     5      16      15       9      17      19      17      14      14      13
#>  6     6      19      17      11      13      14      15      16      14      13
#>  7     7      11      16      11      13      18      13       6      22      16
#>  8     8      17      12      15       9      13      16      19      14      11
#>  9     9      17      15      15       8      11      13      15      21      14
#> 10    10      18      12      17      12      15      12      13      17      17
#> # … with 90 more rows, and 64 more variables: state_9 <int>, state_10 <int>,
#> #   state_11 <int>, state_12 <int>, state_13 <int>, state_14 <int>,
#> #   state_15 <int>, state_16 <int>, state_17 <int>, state_18 <int>,
#> #   state_19 <int>, state_20 <int>, state_21 <int>, state_22 <int>,
#> #   state_23 <int>, state_24 <int>, state_25 <int>, state_26 <int>,
#> #   state_27 <int>, state_28 <int>, state_29 <int>, state_30 <int>,
#> #   state_31 <int>, state_32 <int>, state_33 <int>, state_34 <int>, …

head(results_table_2_df)
#>      rn   id uid id72 uid72
#> 1     1 1000 597    9     9
#> 2     2 1000 618   12    12
#> 3     3 1000 611   17    17
#> 4     4 1000 596   11    11
#> 5     5 1000 588   12    12
#> 6     6 1000 614   26    25
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

another approach, taking advantage of {[vroom](https://vroom.r-lib.org/)} for reading and manipulating large text data files:

### preparation

- load libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(vroom) ## for fast processing of large data files
```

- set input directory (here, I also create sample text data according to your specs):

```
## set input directory (where the input text files are): 
input_dir <- './path/to/your/input_files/'

## create three sample files with 10k lines each:
for (i in 1:3){
    outfile_name = file.path(input_dir, paste0('data_', i, '.csv'))
    df <- data.frame(
        state =  sample(c(0:72), 10000, replace = TRUE),
        id =  sample(c(100:999), 10000, replace = TRUE)
    )
    vroom::vroom_write(df, file = outfile_name)
}
```

read in sample files, merge them into dataframe `df`
(not really, lines are read only when required [see {vroom} link above]

```
## keep source file path in column 'source file':
df <- 
    file.path(input_dir,
           list.files(input_dir, pattern = '\\.csv')
           ) |>
##    read in all matching files, and keep the source file in column 'source file'
    vroom(id = 'source_file') |> 
    mutate(source_file = gsub('.*/', '', source_file)) ## remove path down to filename
```

### processing

- count states per data packet (source file) and reshape into wide table (one column per state):

```
df |> 
    group_by(source_file) |>
    count(state) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = state,
                names_prefix = 'state_',
                values_from = n
                )
```

output:

```
+ # A tibble: 3 x 74
# Groups:   source_file [3]
  source_file state_0 state_1 state_2 state_3 state_4 state_5 state_6 state_7
  <chr>         <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1 data_1.csv      145     138     128     132     133     148     150     133
2 data_2.csv      127     151     140     140     139     139     152     144
3 data_3.csv      140     152     144     150     127     140     125     141
# ... with 65 more variables: state_8 <int>, state_9 <int>, state_10 <int>,
#   state_11 <int>, state_12 <int>, state_13 <int>, state_14 <int>,
#   state_15 <int>, state_16 <int>, state_17 <int>, state_18 <int>,
#   state_19 <int>, state_20 <int>, state_21 <int>, state_22 <int>,
#   state_23 <int>, state_24 <int>, state_25 <int>, state_26 <int>,
#   state_27 <int>, state_28 <int>, state_29 <int>, state_30 <int>,
#   state_31 <int>, state_32 <int>, state_33 <int>, state_34 <int>, ...
# i Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

- obtain various id counts:

```
df |>
    mutate('full_id_count' = n(),
           'full_uid_count' = n_distinct(id)
           ) |>
    group_by(state) |>
    mutate('specif_id_count' = n(),
           'specif_uid_count' = n_distinct(id)
           ) |>
    distinct(across(c(state, full_id_count:specif_uid_count)))
```

output:

```
+ # A tibble: 73 x 5
# Groups:   state [73]
   state full_id_count full_uid_count specif_id_count specif_uid_count
   <dbl>         <int>          <int>           <int>            <int>
 1    31         30000            900             419              339
 2    59         30000            900             394              313
 3     2         30000            900             412              331
 4    20         30000            900             413              329
 5     0         30000            900             412              338
 6    36         30000            900             367              303
 7    55         30000            900             459              361
 8    72         30000            900             395              326
 9    60         30000            900             426              328
10     8         30000            900             405              327
# ... with 63 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Nice approach; great answer +1